# JPA AttributeConverter search predicate in specification

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, converters

I am trying to have a class that has a certain list of objects (specified by another class) persisted in the database as a string (use JPA Converter - all good).
And then I want to use Specification to search inside that string.
What is the best way to create the predicates? I don't seem to understand the connection bettween the AttributeConverter and the Expression in the Specification.

The parent class:

```
@Entity @Table
public class A {
    @Column @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column 
    private String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) 
    private SomeType type;
    @Column(length=1000) @Convert(converter = BConverter.class) 
    private List<B> bList;
    private Integer no;
}
```

The listed object class:

```
public class B{
    private String type;
    private Integer quantity;
}
```

The converter:

```
@Converter
public class BConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<B>, String> {
    private static final String SEPARATOR = ":";
    private static final String LIST_SEPARATOR = ";";

    @Override public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<B> bList) {
        return bList.stream().map(e->convertToString(e)).collect(Collectors.joining(LIST_SEPARATOR));
    }
    @Override public List<B> convertToEntityAttribute(String str) {
        if(str==null || str.isEmpty() ) return null;
        return Arrays.stream(str.split(LIST_SEPARATOR)).map(e->convertFromString(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private String convertToString(B b){
        if(entity==null) return null;
        return b.getType().toString() +SEPARATOR+ b.getQuantity().toString();
    }
    private B convertFromString(String subStr){
        if(subStr==null || subStr.isEmpty() ) return null;
        String[] pair = subStr.split(SEPARATOR);
        return new B(pair[0],Integer.valueOf(pair[1]));
    }
}
```

In the database should look something like:

Table A:

```
id: 1;
name: "Some Name";
type: "THISTYPE";
blist: "TYPE1:11;TYPE2:22";
no: 0;

id: 2;
name: "Other Name";
type: "THISTYPE";
blist: "TYPE1:45;TYPE2:56";
no: 12;
```

I would then like to create Specifications to search over this table for the attributes inside the bList.
For example, search by an entity that contains a B object where type=TYPE1 and a quantity>=30.

```
public static Specification<A> customSpecification(String type, Integer value) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> ///?????????
    }
```

Is there a way to use such specifications where the DB attribute is a String but JAVA only sees the objects?

Comment: Nope. The query is in the database. The JPA Criteria code represents the database query. The JPA spec does NOT define any handling of converters in queries, at all.

Comment: Makes sense. Was hoping for some kind of magic here. I guess I have to really create a database entity for the B class if I out to make it searchable. Thanks.